# How to concatenate SQL queries across 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in my database as follows:

**labs**

```
id
lab_name
lab_owner_id (references id in labs_members table)
lab_manager_id (references id in labs_members table)
```

**labs_members**

```
id
person_id (references id in labs_person table)
```

**labs_person**

```
id
first_name
last_name
```

I need to construct a query to get all of the information from the labs table including the first and last names of the lab owner and lab manager.

I've tried variations of the following query:

```
SELECT labs.id, labs.lab_name, labs.lab_owner_id, labs.lab_manager_id
FROM labs
LEFT JOIN labs_members on labs.lab_owner_id = labs_members.id
LEFT JOIN labs_members on labs.lab_manager_id = labs_members.id
LEFT JOIN labs_person on labs_person.id = labs_members.person_id 
ORDER BY labs.lab_name ASC
```

However, I haven't had any success getting both the lab manager and lab owner names at the same time. I get an error, or either the lab manager name OR the lab owner name (but not both).

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very very close. One more join to the person table and some table aliases and you'll be there:

```
SELECT labs.id, labs.lab_name, labs.lab_owner_id, labs.lab_manager_id, owner_person.first_name, owner_person.last_name, manager_person.first_name, manager_person.last_name
FROM labs
LEFT JOIN labs_members as owner on labs.lab_owner_id = labs_members.id
LEFT JOIN labs_members as manager on labs.lab_manager_id = labs_members.id
LEFT JOIN labs_person as owner_person on owner_person.id = owner.person_id 
LEFT JOIN labs_person as manager_person on manager_person.id = manager.person_id 
ORDER BY labs.lab_name ASC
```

Comment: Excellent! I had to change "labs_members.id" to "owner.id" and the other "labs_members.id" to "manager.id". But, otherwise, that worked perfectly! Thank you for your suggestion.